# Problema con usuarios en la BD

Tags: symfony

Tengo una estructura básica de Symfony 3.3 (la versión 3.4 no acaba de funcionar y la 4 es muy diferente) con dos entidades: **User**, para los usuarios y **Role** para los roles. Varios usuarios podrán tener un role (ManyToOne), y un role podrá estar asignado a varios usuarios (OneToMany). Además, tengo dos usuarios creados en configuración. El archivo **security.yml** incluye:

```
security:
#Como encoder usamos bcrypt para las contraseñas.
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 10
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 10

#Como provider de usuarios definimos en memoria y en base de datos.
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, user_db]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:
                        password: $2y$10$gMoT8xcqB5OK/zBWyqeSqOrQnAqTz/8yxQrmhVhflvs7qw6r65xpC
                        roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                    admin:
                        password: $2y$10$pzphAl3SnvP.UvRmMxKKiuGOoMQghTw7GQ/dZ1s3Kjlm8K0JP73hW
                        roles: 'ROLE_ROOT_ADMIN'
        user_db:
            entity: {class: AppBundle\Entity\User, property: username}
```

El **AppBundle\Entity\User** es así:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * User
 */

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */

class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $familyName;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $language;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $active;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $role;


    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstName.
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Set familyName.
     *
     * @param string $familyName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFamilyName($familyName)
    {
        $this->familyName = $familyName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get familyName.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFamilyName()
    {
        return $this->familyName;
    }

    /**
     * Set username.
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set password.
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set email.
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set language.
     *
     * @param string $language
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLanguage($language)
    {
        $this->language = $language;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get language.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }

    /**
     * Set image.
     *
     * @param string $image
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set active.
     *
     * @param string $active
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setActive($active)
    {
        $this->active = $active;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get active.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getActive()
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * Set role.
     *
     * @param int $role
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    public function __construct($role)
    {
        $this->setRole($role);
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getRoles() method.
    }
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }
}
```

El **AppBundle/Entity/Role** es así:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use AppBundle\Entity\User as User;


/**
 * Role
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $role;


    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set role.
     *
     * @param string $role
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Add user.
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public function addUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->users[] = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove user.
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @return boolean TRUE if this collection contained the specified element, FALSE otherwise.
     */
    public function removeUser(User $user)
    {
        return $this->users->removeElement($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get users.
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

Además, tengo las relaciones definidas en yml. El **AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml** es así:

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        firstName:
            type: string
            length: '100'
            column: first_name
        familyName:
            type: string
            length: '100'
            column: family_name
        username:
            type: string
            length: '50'
            unique: true
        password:
            type: string
            length: '100'
        email:
            type: string
            length: '100'
            unique: true
        language:
            type: string
            length: '2'
        image:
            type: string
            length: '100'
        active:
            type: string
            length: '1'
    manyToOne:
        role:
            type: integer
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Role
            inversedBy: users
            joinColumn:
                name: role
                referencedColumnName: id
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Y el **AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Role.orm.yml** es así:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Role:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\RoleRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        role:
            type: string
            length: '25'
            unique: true
    oneToMany:
        users:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\User
            mappedBy: role
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

El acceso se hace a través de una página con un formulario integrado, así:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    Página principal de la aplicación
    <br><br>

    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('entry_point') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Nombre de usuario o correo electrónico:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

        <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />

        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

El controlador (adaptado a partir de uno copiado de la docu) es así:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

        if ($this->getUser() === null) {
            return $this->render('AppBundle::main_app.html.twig', [
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         => $error,
            ]);
        }

        $userRol = $this->getUser()->getRoles()[0];
        if ($userRol == 'ROLE_ADMIN' || $userRol == 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' || $userRol == 'ROLE_ROOT_ADMIN') {
            $destination = 'admin_index';
        } elseif ($userRol == 'ROLE_USER') {
            $destination = 'user_index';
        } else {
            return $this->render('AppBundle::main_app.html.twig', [
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         => $error,
            ]);
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute($destination);
    }
}
```

Cuando accedo con los usuarios que están *in_memory* no hay problema. Me lo identifica, y me redirecciona correctamente. Sin embargo, si intento acceder con un usuario de la BD, me lanza la siguiente excepción:
**Type error: Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\base_project_dark_q\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider.php on line 94**

Como sólo menciona archivos que son del propio Symfony, que no son los que yo he creado, no sé por donde empezar a mirar. Se supone que debería leer el usuario, leer su rol (por las relaciones entre entidades) y redireccionarme.

¿Alguien sabe lo que estoy haciendo mal? Soy novato en Symfony y cualquier ayuda será agradecida.

Comment: lo que te dice es que espera un array en el construcrtor de la clase , y estas pasando un null

Comment: Hola. Quiero agradecerte tu sugerencia. Sin embargo, me ayudaría si especificases un poco más. ¿Te refieres al constructor de User o al de Role? Que array debería recibir? De donde debería salir? Perdona, pero es que soy nuevo en esto, y no sé muy bien a que te refieres. Además, he creado una Fixture, para cargar datos en la bd de test, y la fixture si graba bien los roles y los users. Es decir, el problema es en la lectura, no en la grabación. Si puedes darme más indicaciones, o alguna referencia en Internet que consultar, te lo agradeceré.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tengo la sospecha que es porque no has implementado un método de la `UserInterface`:

```
public function getRoles()
{
    // TODO: Implement getRoles() method.
}
```

Tienes que retornar una array de roles, de ahí el null que te marca.

Saludos

Comment: Hola. Lo primero, gracias por tu respuesta. En realidad, si lo he puesto, como ves en el código, porque me obliga, al implementar la interface. El problema es que no sé qué tengo que poner dentro del método para obtener esa matriz, así que lo dejé con el TODO, tal como lo has puesto tú.
Perdona, pero es que soy nuevo en esto de Symfony, y no sé qué poner ahí. Si pudieras darme una pista, o remitirme a alguna docu explícita (en la docu de symfony no he hallado la solución), sería genial.

Gracias.

Comment: No hay porque disculparse, es parte del aprendizaje, mira este enlace https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html en la primera parte está la clase user implementada completamente

Comment: Hola, y gracias de nuevo.

Comment: He estado probando lo de esa página, pero no veo como obtener esa matriz. La idea es que los usuarios tienen una propiedad $role (un integer) que se relaciona con el $id de la entidad Role, para recuperar el rol del usuario. Los usuarios tienen un rol, y solo uno, y cada rol puede estar asociado a varios usuarios. Por eso, en la entidad Role he definido $users como ArrayCollection. La propiedad $role de User no puede ser una matriz, es un valor único (cada usuario, un solo rol).

Comment: Se supone que los ficheros orm.yml deberían hacer que, a través del id, se obtuviese el rol del usuario. Al menos, eso me ha parecido entender, tras horas de mirar docu. Debería renombrar la entidad Role a Roles?, Debería modificar algo en las relaciones, o en el __toString() de la entidad User?

Comment: También he probado anulando este método, pero sigue sin funcionar. Se supone que la entidad User debería obtener un objeto Role, y a través de __toString, obtener el rol real del usuario, no?.

Comment: Insisto. Una vez más, gracias por tu ayuda, y disculpa que sea tan pesado, pero es la primera vez que intento montar esto, y creo haberlo probado ya todo (menos la solución correcta, evidentemente).